# What is the reason for using the functions that are allocating memory? in c

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, kernel, malloc

What is the reason for using the functions that are allocating memory? (`malloc` , `ExAllocatePool` ,...)

If every variable or structure does not allocate memory to itself, then why do we use these functions?

Comment: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score. You will be able to upvote once you get enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the reason for using the functions that are allocating memory?

The reason is simple. The same C source code might be used on small computers (mobile phones with a few megabytes) and on super computers (costing millions of €, with terabytes of memory).

Think also of [software portability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability).

A typical example could be to sort an array of numbers. A cheap computer (perhaps the 2€ microprocessor inside your mouse) can sort just an array of a thousands `int`.

But a supercomputer could sort an array of ten billions `int` (that does not fit into your mobile phone).

For examples, look into the source code of [GNU sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_(Unix)) (or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)) or any textbook implementation of [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

How would you code even a simple C compiler (like [tinycc](https://bellard.org/tcc/), which is open source) without allocating memory?

> If every variable or structure does not allocate memory to itself, then why do we use these functions?

Every book on C programming is explaining why and how. See also this [C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c).

As an exercise, code the C program which outputs the longest line in any given textual file. Input files could be small or huge (for example, the source code of [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/)) or the SQL dump of a huge [PostGreSQL](https://postgresql.org/) database.

See also (for Linux) my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) program (generating arbitrarily big C code).

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons to use memory allocation functions:

- so programs can handle a variable amount of data: you could define fixed arrays of a maximum size, but it is more flexible to allocate the required memory once you know the amount needed for a given problem at runtime.
- because some problems require a variable amount of memory depending on the actual data handled, even for a fixed amount data.
- so memory used for a particular task can be reused for other purposes once the task has been completed.